# Install python windows

Tags: python, windows, installation

I want to install python on windows 10, but don't know which one.

```
Download Windows x86 web-based installer
Download Windows x86 executable installer
Download Windows x86 embeddable zip file
Download Windows x86-64 web-based installer
Download Windows x86-64 executable installer
Download Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file
```

These are 3.5 version.

Comment: These are types of installers, web based installer implies you will need internet connection while installing, executable installer don't need internet connection once the installer is downloaded.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal, the executable installer doesn't need an Internet connection for a standard installation. However, some optional components such as the debug binaries and symbols aren't bundled, so installing them does require Internet access.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a 64-bit version of Windows, get the "Windows x86-64 executable installer". If you have a 32-bit version of Windows, or don't know whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows, get the "Windows x86 executable installer".

After downloading it, run it like any program, following the prompts from the wizard.

Also note that Python 3.6 was released just yesterday, so you might as well get that instead of 3.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Go to computer-> properties->System-> System time

If you have 64-bit install x64, if not- install x86